# Can I safely delete XMP files after creating JPEGs?

Tags: photoshop, xmp

If I edit my RAW files in Photoshop, and create JPEG files, can I delete the XMP files which get created?  At this stage, I am not interested in keeping the data of my editing, but I want to make sure that it is not attached in some way to the JPEG I created of my edited photo.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, if your picture is exported in JPEG, it's safe to do whatever you want on the RAW source. XMP files are just an archived history of the processing stages on the RAW file (settings and parameters used), it has nothing to do with the exported JPEG.

However, I would not recommend to delete the XMP files. First, it's just a few more kilobytes (like a droplet in the ocean of heavy RAW files), and second, your future self might be happy to have them (to keep track of your editing, rework on the file, see how you improved in editing, etc.).

Comment: +1, but of course, the XMP file has "everything to do" with making another future copy of that JPG.  Without the XMP, we're back at the unprocessed raw file. There may be worse things, but keeping the XMP is a mighty good idea.

Comment: Isn't XMP attached as metadata in JPEG?

Comment: XMP are only optionaly attached in the JPEG metadata, and frankly there is no reason to attach them there: it's only penalizing file size with useless metadata that might get removed if you upload the file to a server.